# how to upload a file using angular js and html only to my local path

Tags: html, angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive

I tried some code in tutorialpoint and other sites. while clicking upload button it's not storing to my local folder named fileUpload

js file:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

         myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
               restrict: 'A',
               link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                  var modelSetter = model.assign;

                  element.bind('change', function(){
                     scope.$apply(function(){
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                     });
                  });
               }
            };
         }]);

         myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
               var fd = new FormData();
               fd.append('file', file);

               $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
               })

               .success(function(){
               })

               .error(function(){
               });
            }
         }]);

         myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
            $scope.uploadFile = function(){
               var file = $scope.myFile;

               console.log('file is ' );
               console.dir(file);

               var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";//created local folder named as fileUpload in same path where this files or found.
               fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };
         }]);
```

html file :

```
<html>  
   <head>
         <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script src="upload.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body ng-app = "myApp">

      <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
         <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
         <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
      </div>
```

please help me to solve this issue.